# Picasso setIndicatorsEnabled(true) is not working

Tags: android, image, picasso

I'm trying to add the option `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` in my Picasso call but it doesn't work.

This is the call:

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(image)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_img)
    .error(R.drawable.error_img)
    .into(imageView);
```

If I write `.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` before `.load(image)`, nothing works. If I write `.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` after `.into(imageView)`, `.setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` doesn't work.

The Picasso version is 2.5.2 (the last one).

Any suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
Also write this in a single line and then load the Image in your iamgeView in another line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use set indicators enabled, you assume Picasso is a singleton instance when you use Picasso.with(context)....

```
Picasso mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
mPicasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
mPicasso....load().into(imageView);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: happens sometime ;)

Comment: @ÓscarGrande You weren't instantiating anything if you were using `Picasso.with(context)`. That method manages a single instance of Picasso.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, apply it to the single instance of picasso you get from .with(context).

Here you go:

```
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .indicatorsEnabled(true)
            .loggingEnabled(true) //add other settings as needed
            .build();
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso); //apply to default singleton instance
```

you can use above in your Application file in onCreate() (or the first activity that starts if you don't have one, but not really recommended since it's prone to error in case you change launching activity some day).